# Font for length of module

Tags: math-mode

What is the font used for the letter l when it is used to mean the length of a module over a ring? For example,

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SE. It's best to provide a small screenshot of the character and to avoid external links that could become broken in the future. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I added a picture now. Didn't realize it was so convenient to do.

Comment: Do `\newcommand{\modlen}{\ell}` and use `\modlen(E)`. This way, if somebody tells you that the symbol is ugly (it is), you can just change the definition of `\modlen` to be `\newcommand{\modlen}{l}` and recompile, instead of chasing the document for occurrences of `\ell`.

Comment: I actually really like the symbol, that is why I wanted to use it specifically. I initially was using the normal "l" symbol, but I thought it looked very ugly, so I wanted to use this symbol I saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\ell` in math mode: `$\ell(E)$` for example.

[image: result]